# c++ save matrix data into text or XML (better)

Tags: c++, xml, text, matrix

I created a file.dat whith this function

```
int writeData(double* v, int length, FILE* fh)
{
    FILE *Stream;     //Stream for output.
    double*Elem;     //Pointer to all the element to save.

    assert( fh!=NULL );
    Stream = fh;

    Elem=(double*)malloc((length+2)*sizeof(double));//Allocate memory to Elem.
    if(Elem==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't allocate memory for saving the matrix!");
        return(0);
    }

    Elem[0]=(double)1;//Save the dimensions of the matrix.
    Elem[1]=(double)length;

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<length ;i++) 
        Elem[i+2]=v[i];

    if(fwrite((void*)Elem,sizeof(double),(length+2),Stream) < (unsigned)(length+2)) //Save the data.
    {
        printf("Error, can't save the matrix!");
        return(0);
    }
    free(Elem);
    return(1);
}
```

Now I'd like to convert this file into an xml one or into a text file...

Any tips?
Thanks

Comment: So you actually want to save matrix representation in XML or text format? That's what should be mentioned in question title. I've actually edited it. Hope that's what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving the values into text format is easy:

```
int writeTextData(double* v, int length, FILE* fh)
{
   assert( fh!=NULL );
   fprintf(fh, "%d\n", length);
   for(int i=0;i<length ;i++)
      if(fprintf(fh, "%lf ", v[i]) <= 0)
      {
         printf("Error, can't save the matrix!");
         return(0);
      }
   return(1);
}
```

Will save length followed by length numbers.

XML is better written with a help of a library.

While such a simple dataset can be saved into XML manually (through fprintf's) anything more complicated will require you to do complex encoding/escaping and is very error prone, unless you are proficient with XML - as previously said, you'd better use a library (such as libxml)